# Scan a list of assigns in nodejs

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js

My starting point is a file like so:

```
# Default environment to run the app locally.
# In production, the app will probably run on NginX,
# which will act as a reverse proxy
export NODE_ENV='development'
export APPNAME='gigsnet'
export DBHOST='192.168.1.13'
export DBNAME='gigsnet-development'
export IPADDRESS='localhost'
export PORT='8080'
```

This is a simple bash file that sets and exports some environment variables.
I want some nodeJs scripts to use the same file to set the same variables. The idea is to require this file, and have `process.env` magically enriched.

So, I wrote this:

```
var fs = require('fs')
var p = require('path')

fs.readFileSync(p.join(__dirname, 'localEnv.sh')).toString().split('\n').forEach(line => {
  var tokens = line.split(' ')
  if (tokens[0] === 'export') {
    var [ name, value ] = tokens[1].split('=')
    process.env[name] = value.match(/["'](.*?)["']/)[1]
  }
})
```

Problems I have:

- That first line is way too long for my own likings
- The variable `token` could and should have a better name

Looks clunky.

How would you improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The fact that you're parsing BASH means you're probably not worried about portability, which means you probably don't need the `path` module since the directory separator will always be `/`. So, you can replace `p.join(__dirname, 'localEnv.sh')` with `__dirname+'/localEnv.sh'`
- There's a module for [reading stuff line by line](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) already, no need to home-roll it.
- This is a better regex because it takes escaped quotes into account: `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'` [see here](https://regex101.com/r/38xEAP/1).

---

```
require('readline').createInterface({
  input: require('fs').createReadStream(__dirname+'/localEnv.sh')
}).on('line', function (line) {
  var tokens = line.split(' ')
  if (tokens[0] === 'export') {
    var [ name, value ] = tokens[1].split('=')
    process.env[name] = value.match(/"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'/)[1]
  }
});
```